# Swift 4 saving data from json to an array to show it in TableView

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, tableview, swift4

I'm trying to save the data from func getCoinData to an array sympolsCoin and array sympolsCoin  to use it in my TableView

I create this class in the same ViewController.swift file :

```
struct Coin: Decodable {

let symbol : String
let price_usd : String }
```

And this in my View controller class :

```
var coins = [Coin]()


var sympolsCoin = [String]()
var priceUSDcoin = [String]()



func getCoinData(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let jsonURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
    let url = URL(string: jsonURL)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        do {
            self.coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: data!)

            for info in self.coins {

                self.sympolsCoin.append(info.symbol)
                self.priceUSDcoin.append(info.price_usd)

                print("\(self.sympolsCoin) : \(self.priceUSDcoin)")

                completion()
            }

        }


        catch {
            print("Error is : \n\(error)")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And when i use the array in my TableView i got blank table !

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BitcoinTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BitcoinTableViewCell

    cell.coinNameLable.text = sympolsCoin[indexPath.row]
    cell.priceLable.text = priceUSDcoin[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Outlet of tableView in ViewController Class and give it name "tableView" then
Try this code: Swift 4

```
func getCoinData() {
    let jsonURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
    let url = URL(string: jsonURL)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        do {
            self.coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: data!)

            for info in self.coins {

                self.sympolsCoin.append(info.symbol)
                self.priceUSDcoin.append(info.price_usd)

                print("\(self.sympolsCoin) : \(self.priceUSDcoin)")

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

        catch {
            print("Error is : \n\(error)")
        }
  }.resume()
}
```

Call this function in ViewDidLoad like this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getCoinData()
}
```

Comment: I have a small problem ..when the app load up nothing to show up in the table view until i scroll down or up then the data show!

Comment: go to your getCoinData(), replace "self.tableView.reloadData()" with DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `JSONDecoder` the entire logic to create and populate `sympolsCoin` and `priceUSDcoin` is pointless and redundant.

```
struct Coin: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbol, priceUSD = "price_usd"
    }
    let symbol : String
    let priceUSD : String 
}
```

---

```
var coins = [Coin]()
```

The completion handler is redundant, too. Just reload the table view on the main thread after receiving the data:

```
func getCoinData() {
    let jsonURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
    let url = URL(string: jsonURL)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            self.coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error is : \n\(error)")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` load the data

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getCoinData()
}
```

In `cellForRow` update the UI

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BitcoinTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BitcoinTableViewCell

    let coin = coins[indexPath.row]
    cell.coinNameLable.text = coin.symbol
    cell.priceLable.text = coin.priceUSD

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the tableView from the main thread. As a good lesson to learn: Always update the UI from the Main Thread. Always.

```
do {
        self.coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: data!)

        for info in self.coins {

            self.sympolsCoin.append(info.symbol)
            self.priceUSDcoin.append(info.price_usd) 

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            print("\(self.sympolsCoin) : \(self.priceUSDcoin)")

            completion()
        }

    }
```

There is, however another problem with your code the way you have your labels setup won't work. TableViewCells get reused so I'm guessing you have @IBOutlets for them somewhere else. What you should do is declare a label constant in cellForRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let coinNameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel
    coinNameLabel.text = sympolsCoin[indexPath.row]
    let priceNameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    priceNameLabel.text = priceUSDcoin[indexPath.row]
}
```

The above code assumes you've setup two labels with the tags 100 and 101 in your storyboard(assuming your using one)

Answer (score -1):

**

```
// First View Controller
//
//
//
import UIKit
struct Countory : Decodable {
    let name: String
    let capital: String
    let region: String
    let alpha2Code: String
}
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  var listArr = [Countory]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        let url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj) {(data, responds, Error) in
         do {
          self.listArr = try JSONDecoder().decode([Countory].self, from: data!)
             for country in self.listArr {

                    print("Country",country.name)
                    print("###################")
                    print("Capital",country.capital)
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(" not ")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.listArr.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.label1.text = "Name: \(listArr[indexPath.row].name)"
        cell.lable2.text = listArr[indexPath.row].capital
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let homeView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
          homeView.res = listArr[indexPath.row].region
          homeView.alpha = listArr[indexPath.row].alpha2Code
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeView, animated: true)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
}
// SecondViewController
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!

    var res = ""
    var alpha = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.label3.text = res
        self.label4.text = alpha

    }

}
```

**